# Unclear understanding on Lowest Common Ancestor(LCA) Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, least-common-ancestor, lowest-common-ancestor

I was trying to learn LCA algorithm **O(nlog n) preprocessing and O(log n) query**.I am reading it from a russian site with help of google translate.But it is not translating good and I am having some tough time understanding it.Can anybody help me with this ?

This is pseudo code I have taken from that website

```
int n, l; 

vector <vector <int>> g;

vector <int> tin, tout;

int timer;

vector <vector <int>> up;

void dfs (int v, int p = 0) 
{
  tin [v] = ++ timer;
  up [v] [0] = p;
  for (int i = 1; i <= l; i ++)               /** 3)What is this going
     up [v] [i] = up [up [v] [i-1]] [i-1];

  for (i = 0 size_t; i <g [v] .size (); i ++) 
   {
      to g = int [v] [i];
        if (to! = p)
           dfs (to, v);
   }
   tout [v] = ++ timer;
 }

bool upper (int a, int b) 
{
  return tin [a] <= tin [b] && tout [a]> = tout [b];
}

int lca (int a, int b) 
{
  if (upper (a, b)) return a;
  if (upper (b, a)) return b;

  for (int i = l; i> = 0; --i)              /** 2)What is this going
    if (! upper (up [a] [i], b))
        a = up [a] [i];

  return up [a] [0];

}

int main () {

... Read n and g ...

tin.resize (n), tout.resize (n), up.resize (n);
l = 1;                                    
                                      /** 0)What is 'l' used for ?
while ((1 << l) <= n) ++ l;           /** 1)What is this going
for (int i = 0; i <n; i ++) 
  up [i] .resize (l + 1);
dfs (0);

for (;;) //->query loop
  {
    int a, b; // The current query
    int res = lca (a, b); // Response to a request
  }

}
```

**What I have understood**

- I know we are traversing the graph and storing the in-time and out-time of every vertex.
- I understand what `up[i][j]` is It is the `2^j` ancestor of `i` vertex.
- I understand why `up[v][0]=p` (because `2^0`i.e first ancestor of vertex `v` is its   father only)
- I understand what upper function do.It decides which vertex occured before `A` or `B`.
- I understand upper`(a,b)` comes out to be true than lca is `A` and similarly second step.

**What I don't understand is mentioned by me in the pseudo code.Please help me and please confirm if I have understood everything correct or not.**

**P.S->** Sorry for my english.Not much comfortable with this.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/#Lowest%20Common%20Ancestor%20(LCA))?

Comment: @pham Trung Yes I actually visited topcoder first.But I was little bit disappointed."Okay we are going to find this value using recurence relation given below"-I mean you guys would understand easily but it I personally think sparse table and this algorithm are very cut-to-cut.